# Colombian Citizen travel to Germany through Ireland (Dublin)

Tags: visas, transit, dublin, colombian-citizens

Hi my friend (Colombian citizen) is travelling to USA in October and stays with me (my friend has a visa for USA) until December when we travel to Germany. However we have a layover of 4 hours in Dublin (Ireland) in terminal 2 and from terminal 2 goes our connection flight to Berlin. I have read the visa requirement and I am not sure if my friends needs a transit visa or a visa at all. We checked Germany and all is good with Germany because my friend is staying less then 90 days. So I am really concerned about Ireland and would like to know if my friend needs to apply for a visa for Ireland.

Answer (score 4):

The rules for transiting in Dublin, as given by Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Passengers
>   transiting through Dublin (DUB) with a confirmed onward ticket for a
>   flight to a third country. They must:
>
> - arrive at and depart from Terminal 2, and
> - be transiting between 04:00 and 16:00 on the same calendar day, and
> - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
> - have documents required for the next destination.